# Can I toggle the NetLimiter driver through the command line?

Tags: command-line, drivers, netlimiter

I've installed NetLimiter 3 and I was wondering how I can enable/disable its driver using the command line. I need to be able to programmatically toggle the driver.

Enabling it through the GUI is simple:

1. Open the `Network and Sharing Center` and clicking the interface (`LAN` for me)

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Click `Properties`

   [image: Screenshot]
3. Uncheck `NetLimiter Ndis Driver` and click OK.

   [image: Screenshot]

Can I do this through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Windows, you can try to use the [Netsh](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Something like:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Netlimiter Ndis Driver" admin=disabled
```

to disable and

```
netsh interface set interface name="Netlimiter Ndis Driver" admin=enabled
```

to turn it back on.